# Facebook ads like charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, charts, diagram

I'm looking for a javascript library that can create charts similar to the Facebook ads reach chart:
http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/421/4163691067.jpg
jQuery or highcharts would be preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: I did some more research and apparently Facebook is using an add on for the flot chart library (http://code.google.com/p/flot/) written by Cliff Chang called flot-circles.  
I couldn't find it anywhere though and I doubt it is open source...

Answer (score 0):

I love Raphael.js ... It's cross browser compatible and works in ie7 and up (it might work in older browsers too, I just haven't tested)

[raphael.js pie chart example](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html)

Comment: Yeah, raphael.js is nice, but would require to write a lot of custom code.  
So this is not the answer I've been looking for...

Comment: You can simply render SVG using Raphael.js